# SQL Server: how to have one result with 2 requests?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a beginner in SQL and I have a question.

I have 2 requests. The first give that kind of result:

```
Id  Event      Name   Last Name  Address   City   Phone number
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1   159784623  NAME1  LASTNAME1  ADDRESS1  CITY1  PHONENUMBER1
2   159784623  NAME2  LASTNAME2  ADDRESS2  CITY2  PHONENUMBER2
3   159784623  NAME3  LASTNAME3  ADDRESS3  CITY3  PHONENUMBER3
4   159784623  NAME4  LASTNAME4  ADDRESS4  CITY4  PHONENUMBER4
5   159784623  NAME5  LASTNAME5  ADDRESS5  CITY5  PHONENUMBER5
6   159784623  NAME6  LASTNAME6  ADDRESS6  CITY6  PHONENUMBER6
```

The 2nd request give me an array of other parameter:

```
Id  Parameter   ParameterType  Event
-----------------------------------
1   ADULT       INTEGER        159784623 
2   CHILDREN    INTEGER        159784623
3   CAR         BOOLEAN        159784623
4   HOTEL       LABEL          159784623
5   RESTAURANT  LABEL          159784623
```

My question: is it possible to do a request that create in the 1st array a column For each row of the 2nd columns?

If it's possible, can you explain it to me?

I must confess I don't where to search.

The result I want is this:

```
Id  Event      Name   Last Name  Address   City   Phone number  Adult  Children  Car  Hotel  Restaurant
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1  159784623  NAME1  LASTNAME1  ADDRESS1  CITY1  PHONENUMBER1
 2  159784623  NAME2  LASTNAME2  ADDRESS2  CITY2  PHONENUMBER2
 3  159784623  NAME3  LASTNAME3  ADDRESS3  CITY3  PHONENUMBER3
 4  159784623  NAME4  LASTNAME4  ADDRESS4  CITY4  PHONENUMBER4
 5  159784623  NAME5  LASTNAME5  ADDRESS5  CITY5  PHONENUMBER5
 6  159784623  NAME6  LASTNAME6  ADDRESS6  CITY6  PHONENUMBER6
```

Thanks.

EDIT:

Actually I can't alter this table because for each event the number of rows in the second array can change. So sometimes I must add 5 columns but sometimes 47 or nothing in the first array.

And I'm querying only one Event at a time.

Comment: Empty Adult, Children etc columns?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  And no, this is not possible using a simple query.  You would need to use dynamic SQL to create and populate the table.  The syntax for that depends entirely on the database.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: @jarlh yes the columns must be empty.

Comment: @jarlh i don't know how to do an "excel" table  in a question.

Comment: Maybe usefull: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516696/add-column-dynamically-with-select-query

Comment: Sorry Ramp, it's not clear what you want to do, If it´s just to add empty columns to your first table simply use alter database to add them.

Comment: @Erick actually i can't alter this table because for each event the number of rows in the second array can change. So sometimes i must add 5 columns but sometimes 47 or nothing in the first array. That's why i ask this question.

Comment: So you're always querying only one Event at a time?

Comment: @Christian yes just one event

Comment: And where do you want to display/use the query results? Is it a web app or you need the results in Excel...? This would be a good information to add to your question.

Comment: @Christian I want to generate a json to create a Datatables.so a Web app

Comment: OK, so keep using two queries and mix their results together with whatever programming language you're using to generate the JSON. SQL is not the right tool for things like this in my opinion. If you really need to use SQL, you can create a stored procedure that generates the SQL as a string (aka dynamic SQL) and executes it. Then call this stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add additional columns with empty or otherwise static content, you can just add them to the `SELECT` clause as in

```sql
SELECT
   Id,
   Event,
   CAST(NULL as INT) as Adult
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: As an FYI, the `CAST` isn't needed if an `int` is wanted. If not defined, a column of `NULL` will be returned as an `int`. As show here: `SELECT system_type_name FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(N'SELECT NULL AS N FROM sys.tables;', NULL, NULL);`